# cannot find symbol class OnCompleteListener

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I'm following a tutorial on how to make registration using firebase and i copy paste the code from firebase tools which is the "sign up new users" and it show error "error: cannot find symbol class OnCompleteListener"

I've tried to change the version on dependency but it doesn't solve the issue.

```
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

expected android studio to recognize the symbol but its not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this on **build.gradle  (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
}
```

and dont forget to import this

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
```

hope this help..

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. also need to import these as well:


`import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;`

Answer (score 2):

OnCompleteListener is part of the [Play Services Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks).  You can find the [JavaDoc for that class here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnCompleteListener).  It's not terribly clear from the JavaDoc, but the package of the class is com.google.android.gms.tasks, and you can import it as such:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
```